# Using early clock to print the time along with function name in x86

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, linux-device-driver, x86-64, ftrace

I want to print the timestamp for each function in x86. I am able to print the function name during early boot but I want to print the timestamp also similar to ftrace:

`TASK-PID    CPU#    TIMESTAMP  FUNCTION
    | |       |          |         |
 bash-16939 [000]  6075.461561: mutex_unlock <-tracing_set_tracer
<ide>-0     [001]  6075.461562: _spin_unlock_irqrestore <-hrtimer_get_next_event`

Since ftrace can be used after boot they use some clock source to get timestamp.
But I want to print timestamp during early boot and I have heard we can use `early clock` registers concept in x86 to achieve this. How can I use this to print timestamp? I have found that there are clocksources like `tsc`,`hpet` and `acpi_pm`. Can I use these during early boot. If so how?